# How to solve illegalstateexception circular dependencies cannot exist in relativelayout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am going an unusual error in my layout. I search in the google but not really found proper solution.

**My Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/round_cell_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/music_cell"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relative_cell_view"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<com.mdotbuz.support.RoundCornerImage
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/music"/>

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_cell_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/music_cell"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/scondary_color"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/music_cell" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_cell"
android:background="#ff44cc"
android:orientation="horizontal">        
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/favourite"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="5dp"/>


 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favourite"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/white_arrow"/>

</RelativeLayout>  
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/image_cell" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/music_cell"
      android:background="#ff44cc"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/white_arrow" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/view_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#ff4455"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```

This is the above xml layout , I have given the proper RelativeLayout for all ui elements but don't know , where the error is coming exactly? , so please go through it and let me know , some solution.

Comment: element with some id should appear before this id is used, views should not be related to each other .... `<view id="view1" toLeftOf="view2" /><view id="view2" toRightOf="view1" />` <= obviously you have something like this ...

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular reference here:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/music_cell" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_cell"

...
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_cell" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/music_cell"
```

`image_cell` is to the right of `music_cell` which is to the left of `image_cell`. You'll have to remove one of the layout instructions and anchor, if you haven't, the other cell within the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The first `RelativeLayout` and the last one don't have the closing tag. `Add </RelativeLayout>` twice at the end.